# set export values to list dropdown with iText7 c#

Tags: c#, forms, itext7

## how to set export values to list dropdown with iText7 and c# ?

```
using iText.Forms;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;

string fileIn = getFullPath("prueba");
string fileOut = getFullPath("Prueba_sal");
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileIn);
PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(fileOut);
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter);
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(document, false);

IList<PdfObject> options = new List<PdfObject>();
options.Add(new PdfString("Any"));
options.Add(new PdfString("8.30 am - 12.30 pm"));
options.Add(new PdfString("12.30 pm - 4.30 pm"));
options.Add(new PdfString("4.30 pm - 8.30 pm"));
options.Add(new PdfString("8.30 pm - 12.30 am"));
options.Add(new PdfString("12.30 am - 4.30 am"));
options.Add(new PdfString("4.30 am - 8.30 am"));
PdfArray arr = new PdfArray(options);

PdfFormField dropdownF = form.GetField("lista1");
dropdownF.SetOptions(arr);
```

And I get the list Dropdown in PDF Form but without export values; i want to add the list of export values with each option